# I'm trying to create a dictionary from a list, where the first value is the key and the second the value and so on

Tags: list, dictionary

I'm getting the dictionary, but my code is omitting and replacing tow of the values.
The list is:

```
['20', 'Gunsmoke', '30', 'The Simpsons', '10', 'Will & Grace', '14', 'Dallas', '20', 'Law & Order', '12', 'Murder, She Wrote']
```

My code is:

```
t = 0
n = 1
for i in show_list[0:-1:2]:
    show_dict[show_list[t]] = show_list[n]
    t += 2
    n += 2
print(show_dict)
```

And the outcome is:

```
{'20': 'Law & Order', '30': 'The Simpsons', '10': 'Will & Grace', '14': 'Dallas', '12': 'Murder, She Wrote'}
```

I can't figure out why its replacing '20', 'Gunsmoke' with '20', 'Law & Order'

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` (`show_list` is your list from the question):

```py
d = dict(zip(show_list[::2], show_list[1::2]))
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'20': 'Law & Order', '30': 'The Simpsons', '10': 'Will & Grace', '14': 'Dallas', '12': 'Murder, She Wrote'}
```